# (R) Filter rows based on string names if the only resulting match in another column is NA

Tags: r, filter, match, aggregate, tidyverse

The title may sound kinda weird but I have found no way of better defining my issue.

Here an example data set:

```
test = data.frame(genus = c("Acicarpha", "Acicarpha", "Acicarpha", "Acicarpha", "Acisanthera", "Acisanthera", "Acisanthera", "Acisanthera", "Acmella", "Acmella"), sp1 = c("NA", "bonariensis", "bonariensis", "spathulata", NA, "variabilis", "variabilis", "variabilis", NA, NA))
```

As you can see, I have a few species names (`genus+sp1`) possible: *Acicarpha NA*, *Acicarpha bonariensis*, *Acicarpha spathulata*, *Acisanthera variabilis*, *Acisanthera NA*, and *Acmella NA*.

Here's the deal: I'm trying to select only the row related to Acmella NA since the **only** returning value on the `sp1` column is NA. Other species also have NA, but they do not have **only** NA. How can I do this? I'm bashing my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that does what I think you're asking for. It has four steps:

1. Group the rows by `genus`.
2. Make a new column called `all_sp1_na` that is `TRUE` if all of each genus's `sp1` observations are `NA`, `FALSE` otherwise (i.e. `FALSE` if at least one `sp1` observation is *not* `NA` for that genus).
3. Filter for rows where `all_sp1_na` is true.
4. Remove the temporary column `all_sp1_na`.

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  group_by(genus) %>%
  mutate(all_sp1_na = all(is.na(sp1))) %>%
  filter(all_sp1_na) %>%
  select(-all_sp1_na)
```

And it gives this result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   genus [1]
  genus   sp1  
  <chr>   <chr>
1 Acmella NA   
2 Acmella NA
```

Let me know if you're looking for something else.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(test, !genus %in% genus[!is.na(sp1)])
     genus  sp1
9  Acmella <NA>
10 Acmella <NA>
```

---

Or with `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
    filter(!genus %in% genus[!is.na(sp1)])
```